# How to throw an error window in Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows

What's the easiest way to generate an error window for a Python script in Windows?
Windows-specific answers are fine; please don't reply how to generate a custom Tk window.

Comment: What's wrong with Tk? It is very easy to create a message box with tkinter.

Comment: I was looking for a one-liner

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Constantin is almost correct, but his example will produce garbage text.  Make sure that the text is unicode.  I.e.,

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Error", u"Error", 0)
```

...and it'll work fine.

Comment: Almost correct :) In 3.x `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Error", "Error", 0)` would have worked as expected, and `u"Error"` would not compile at all.

Comment: Ah, good to know.  It's gonna be a major headache when I'm forced to move to py3k!

Comment: I'm using 2.5 for compatibility reasons, so Chris's is what I needed.
Moving to 3.0 really is going to be very difficult!

Comment: @Scribble Master, fortunately official 2to3 conversion tool removes much of that headache.

Comment: You probably want `ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, u"Error", u"Error", 16)` -- this gives you the error icon + sound

Answer (score 3):

If you need a GUI error message, you could use [EasyGui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/):

```
>>> import easygui as e
>>> e.msgbox("An error has occured! :(", "Error")
```

Otherwise a simple `print("Error!")` should suffice.

Comment: That works, thanks! Not so great that I have to install another library, though. And it is based on Tkinter. I wanted something that would call the windows api directly.

Answer (score 2):

If i recall correctly (don't have Windows box at the moment), the `ctypes` way is:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, u"Error", u"Error", 0)
```

[ctypes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/ctypes.html) is a standard module.

Note: For Python 3.x you don't need the `u` prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a one-liner using tkinter.

```
import tkMessageBox

tkMessageBox.showerror('error title', 'error message')
```

Here is some documentation for [pop-up dialogs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/dialogs.html#tkMessageBox).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, thanks!
I do prefer the direct win32 call, though

Comment: Note that with this answer you will also get a main window.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280637/tkinter-messagebox-without-window) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [GUI](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) section of the Python Wiki for info on message boxs