# Tkinter messagebox without window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to show an info window in my python script running on ubuntu. I'm using the following code:

```
import tkMessageBox
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")
```

This works, but there's an empty window displayed, with the message box on top. How can I get rid of the window and just centre the message box on the screen (window manager is gnome 2)?

This is just to display some info from a command line script (a password which is why I don't want to just echo it to the console).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Tkinter must have a root window. If you don't create one, one will be created for you. If you don't want this root window, create it and then hide it:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")
```

Your other choice is to *not* use tkMessageBox, but instead put your message in the root window. The advantage of this approach is you can make the window look exactly like you want it to look.

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Say Hello")
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello World")
label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
button = tk.Button(root, text="OK", command=lambda: root.destroy())
button.pack(side="bottom", fill="none", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

(personally I would choose a more object-oriented approach, but I'm trying to keep the code small for this example)

Comment: Is there any way I can make the text selectable so I can copy it?

Comment: @user1491250: yes. Use a text widget instead of a label. You can tweak the borderwidth and colors to make it look like a label.

Comment: With the first option...Is there a way to finish the app when pressing the "OK" button in the dialog? Right now, the dialog doesn't close when I do (maybe I should do a root.destroy(), but I don't know how to do it just after pressing OK)

Answer (score 12):

To avoid a "flash" as the root window is created, use this slight variation on the accepted answer:

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.withdraw()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Say Hello", "Hello World")
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3:

```
import tkinter, tkinter.messagebox

def messagebox(title, text):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title, text)
    root.destroy()
```

With native Windows support when `pywin32` is installed:

```
try:
    from win32ui import MessageBox
except ImportError:
    import tkinter, tkinter.messagebox
    def MessageBox(text, title):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title, text)
        root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Import messagebox individually. For example:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
```

or

```
from tkinter import messagebox
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for python 3

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()
messagebox.showinfo("Window Title", "Your Message")
```