# Tkfiledialog: Where does the extra window come from?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, user-input, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create a very simple GUI for my Python script; it's just asking the user to put in the name of a directory. Following the docs [here](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog), I did the following:

```
import tkFileDialog
outputdir = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(title="Outputfolder: Please choose a folder to copy files into")
```

This indeed lets me pick a directory, but

- a second (empty, white) box, simply labeled "Tk", appears
- this box is on top of the file dialog that is relevant to the user

Why does this happen? And how do I get rid of it?

The [tutorials](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#dialogs) and [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html) did not really mentions this kind of issue, and I must admit that I am still slightly confused about the whole Tk-business in Python.

I am working in Python 2 on a Mac.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280637/tkinter-messagebox-without-window The question isn't identical to yours, but it is essentially the same problem.

Comment: thank you sir, worked perfectly. (apparently Tkinter creates a new window by default, so one needs to trick it by creating and then withdrawing this new window beforehand).