# tkinter messagebox without console

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, tkmessagebox

Facing a problem when converting my `.py` file to `.exe` using `pyinstaller --noconsole`, the messagebox won't work in exe file except if I created it without using `--noconsole` or `--windowed`.
I have tried to not use `--noconsole` and use `.pyw` file instead but this won't make the the console hidden when running the `.exe` file

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280637/tkinter-messagebox-without-window

Comment: am already using a window but it seems the app is closing since the console is not running and that is why the button doesn't trigger the func.
maybe if there is way to keep the application running as long as the tkinter window is open

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with `tkinter`'s `messagebox`. Please [edit] your post to include relevant code (see [mcve]). If you're using a library other than `tkinter` or other than the ones which come bundled with Python, check if you include them using something like `--add-data` or `--hidden-import`. Also, please include the exact PyInstaller command you're using in the CMD/terminal to create the EXE file.

Comment: "the msgbox wont work in exe file"  This does not tell us much...  Please post the error code you are receiving and create a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when removing the print(f'Error printing barcode')
it works fine with me

```
       try:
            mysocket.connect((host, port))  # connecting to host
        except:
            host = another_host
            mysocket.connect((host, port))
        mysocket.send(zpl_b)
        mysocket.close()  # closing connection
        print(f'Error printing barcode')
        mbox= res +" barcode printed. from study: "+ dict_data["study_id"]
        messagebox.showinfo("Printed",mbox)
```